# Surface Area Estimation Using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

How can I estimate the surface area of an irregular object placed in front of a webcam at a fixed distance from the camera, using Python's OpenCV library? This quick video demonstrates what I mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owvwgTwJT2Y

Comment: The video you linked is not using a simple webcam, its using a Kinect (libfreenect) which has depth sensors. With depth information you can segment, track and you have volumetrical information of the surface. 
With only 2D information from a normal RGB webcam, you d probably need to segment for the object in question and take into account possible object orientation and probably use machine learning to achieve anything good.

Comment: @Diedre thank you for your contribution. You are right, but in my case I only need 2D surface measurement because the object is a board that will be placed on a fixed plane perpendicular to the camera, which would make it possible to measure the surface area without depth sensors. I wrote python code that can detect and draw the contour of the object but I still don't know how to calculate the surface area.

Comment: Use the depth data. For your use and similar uses it would be a waste of time to use only 2D data when 3D data is available. From the video I wouldn't consider the distance to be "fixed"--it appears to vary a bit. But if you want to just use 2D data, and if you don't need an accurate answer, then you can place a ruler at the desired depth, count (manually) how many pixels stretch across 10mm, and the calculate mm/pixel. From there you can estimate area. But if you use 3D data, you could calculate a relatively consistent area for the same object at any distance within the sensor's range.